# Forming 12AWG Copper Stranded Wire

Tags: wire

Looking for some advice on how I would go about bending 12 AWG stranded copper wire into a U shape.
It is part of a harness that gimbals, so I’d like to form it to reduce the preload exerted onto the electronics board it’s soldered to.

Comment: the solder joint should not "feel" any stress from the wire movement ... the wire end should be anchored before the solder joint

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. When I want to bend 12 AWG stranded copper wire, I just grab it with my hands and bend it. Is there something which prevents that from being a solution for you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are wire benders that will form wire into an even curve but they're usually for jewelry that is smaller than your wire or industrial applications that use larger wire, or are extremely expensive. Maybe print a mandrel?